# Netty 4 - The pool returns a channel which is not yet ready to send the the actual message

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I have created an inbound handler of type SimpleChannelInboundHandler and added to pipeline. My intention is every time a connection is established, I wanted to send an application message called session open message and make the connection ready to send the actual message. To achieve this, the above inbound handler 
over rides channelActive() where session open message is sent, In response to that I would get a session open confirmation message. Only after that I should be able to send any number of actual business message. I am using FixedChannelPool and initialised as follows. This works well some time on startup. But if the remote host closes the connection, after that if a message is sent calling the below sendMessage(), the message is sent even before the session open message through channelActive() and its response is obtained. So the server ignores the message as the session is not open yet when the business message was sent.

What I am looking for is, the pool should return only those channel that has called channelActive() event which has already sent the session open message and it has got its session open confirmation message from the server. How to deal with this situation?

```
public class SessionHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<byte[]> {
    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelActive(ctx);
        if (ctx.channel().isWritable()) {
            ctx.channel().writeAndFlush("open session message".getBytes()).;
        }
    }
}

// At the time of loading the applicaiton
public void init() {
    final Bootstrap bootStrap = new Bootstrap();
    bootStrap.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).remoteAddress(hostname, port);
    fixedPool = new FixedChannelPool(bootStrap, getChannelHandler(), 5);

    // This is done to intialise connection and the channelActive() from above handler is invoked to keep the session open on startup
    for (int i = 0; i < config.getMaxConnections(); i++) {
        fixedPool.acquire().addListener(new FutureListener<Channel>() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(Future<Channel> future) throws Exception {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {

                } else {
                    LOGGER.error(" Channel initialzation failed...>>", future.cause());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

//To actually send the message following method is invoked by the application.

```
public void sendMessage(final String businessMessage) {
    fixedPool.acquire().addListener(new FutureListener<Channel>() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(Future<Channel> future) throws Exception {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                Channel channel = future.get();
                if (channel.isOpen() && channel.isActive() && channel.isWritable()) {
                    channel.writeAndFlush(businessMessage).addListener(new GenericFutureListener<ChannelFuture>() {
                        @Override
                        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                                // success msg
                            } else {
                                // failure msg
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    fixedPool.release(channel);
                }
            } else {
                // Failure
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no specific reason that you need to use a `FixedChannelPool` then you can use another data structure (List/Map) to store the Channels. You can add a channel to the data structure after sending open session message and remove it in the `channelInactive` method.

If you need to perform bulk operations on channels you can use a [ChannelGroup](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html) for the purpose.

If you still want you use the `FixedChannelPool` you may set an attribute in the channel on whether open message was sent:

```
ctx.channel().attr(OPEN_MESSAGE_SENT).set(true);
```

you can get the attribute as follows in your `sendMessage` function:

```
boolean sent = ctx.channel().attr(OPEN_MESSAGE_SENT).get();
```

and in the `channelInactive` you may set the same to false or remove it.

Note `OPEN_MESSAGE_SENT` is an `AttributeKey`:

```
public static final AttributeKey<Boolean> OPEN_MESSAGE_SENT = AttributeKey.valueOf("OPEN_MESSAGE_SENT");
```

Comment: Thank you Riyafa, Is there a way this can be achieved in FixedChannelPool?

Comment: Thanks again Riyafa, that is exactly what I am doing now and but when I check the value in sendMessage() function this value is not set. So I wanted to wait until this value is set. Is there a standard way to introduce a wait there without writing a while loop that waits until this value is set before I call channel.writeAndFlush(). I mean something like Channel channel = future.get(); should wait until this value is set or something like that?

Comment: Define your own future and notify that.

Comment: FixedChannelPool is such a useless component that it should be deleted from Netty

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old question, but I stumbled across the similar issue, not quite the same, but my issue was the `ChannelInitializer` in the `Bootstrap.handler` was never called.
The solution was to add the pipeline handlers to the pool handler's `channelCreated` method.

Here is my pool definition code that works now:

```java
pool = new FixedChannelPool(httpBootstrap, new ChannelPoolHandler() {
    @Override
    public void channelCreated(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(HTTP_CODEC, new HttpClientCodec());
        pipeline.addLast(HTTP_HANDLER, new NettyHttpClientHandler());
    }
    @Override
    public void channelAcquired(Channel ch) {
        // NOOP
    }
    @Override
    public void channelReleased(Channel ch) {
        // NOOP
    }
}, 10);
```

So in the `getChannelHandler()` method I assume you're creating a `ChannelPoolHandler` in its `channelCreated` method you could send your session message (`ch.writeAndFlush("open session message".getBytes());`) assuming you only need to send the session message once when a connection is created, else you if you need to send the session message every time you could add it to the `channelAcquired` method.